# "this unusual instrument" with plural antecedents

Tags: demonstrative, proximity-agreement

The singular noun phrase "this unusual instrument" in the following refers to plural antecedents "them" and "glass harps." Is this practice acceptable in a school essay?

> **Glass harps** haven’t entirely disappeared, though. You can still find some street musicians playing **them** to entertain large crowds. If you’re lucky enough to catch such a performance, sit back, relax, and enjoy the beautiful sounds of **this unusual instrument**.

I'd appreciate your help.

Answer (score 3):

"glass harps" is as generic as "this unusual instrument".

Grammatically speaking, "them" refers to "glass harps" and is required because of the plural subject:

- Some street musician**s** play **them** to entertain large crowds. (Musician**s** play glass harp**s**.)

In the last sentence, "this instrument" is correct because glass harps are one type of instrument. "this instrument" is not used to refer to a single object but to glass harps in general.

Comment: This is definitely correct in informal usage, but the clash in number agreement makes me doubt its acceptability in a school essay.

Comment: @Apollyon I find it to be correct even in formal English. "these unusual instruments" would also be correct but might be interpreted as referring to different kinds of instrument. "this unusual instrument" unequivocally refers to the glass harp.

Comment: How about "such unusual instruments"?

Comment: There would be two "such"s in the same sentence. Besides, "such" intensifies the unusual nature of glass harps. Within the text, "this unusual..." sounds better than "such unusual..."

Comment: I am thinking about the issue of shifts in number, an issue that arises not only on the sentence level but also on the paragraph level.

Do you know how to distinguish the unfavorable kinds of number shifts from the appropriate kinds?

Comment: The clue lies in distinguishing between genericness and specificity.  The former will enable number shifs, while the latter will not.

Answer (score 1):

> Glass harps haven’t entirely disappeared, though. You can still find
>   some street musicians playing them to entertain large crowds. If
>   you’re lucky enough to catch such a performance, sit back, relax, and
>   enjoy the beautiful sounds of this unusual instrument.

That is perfectly correct because at the time of the performance we assume you are listening to a single glass harp, not many. Note: I personally would remove the comma before the word "though".